# AJAX POST request with JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

So I'm trying to implement a calendar - fullCalendar to be precise - with AJAX so that Ill be able to store events in database. I followed this http://developer-paradize.blogspot.si/2013/06/jquery-fullcalendar-integration-with.html , but it didn't work with adding events. I modified my code a bit and PHP script that stores data gathered through POST request in database, seems to work fine when I send request with Postman, but when I try to post with AJAX nothing happens.
PHP script for adding event data in database:

```
<?php
$title = $_POST['title'];
$start = $_POST['start'];   
$end = $_POST['end'];   
$url = $_POST['url'];

try {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tracksto', 'admingZZX92g', 'LwQ1Wwi6N2I3');
} catch(Exception $e) {
    exit('Unable to connect to db.');
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO evenement (title, start, end, url) VALUES (:title, :start, :end, :url)";
$q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':title'=>$title, ':start'=>$start, ':end'=>$end, ':url'=>$url));
```

My AJAX call:

```
var data = { "title":"Gregor", "start":"2016-05-10 00:00:00", "end":"2016-05-10 00:00:00", "url":"www.renting.si" };
       $.ajax({
           url: '"http://localhost/gui/calendar/add_events.php',
           contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
           data: data,
           type: "POST",
           success: function(json) {
                alert('Added Successfully');
           }

      });
```

If I have variables title,start,end,url defined and set data to:

```
data: 'title='+title+'&start='+start+'&end='+end+'&url='+url,
```

same thing, nothing happens.
In POSTMAN the request looks like this:
[POSTMAN POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEafw.png)

The script normally processes this request and stores data in database. Is my AJAX call wrong or is there something else?

Comment: Yes. This ajax call is in a function that is triggered with a selection on calendar. Right before the call i have a prompt for title which is executed so I guess ajax method is executed aswell? Is there a way to check if the call wasnt executed? But did you see my request with postman? If i set contentType there to application/json the request is wrong, to be precise I get "undefined index" error for $_POST[...] variables

Comment: Yes, you can see all the network traffic being sent through the network tab of the console. You can also check to see the response to this request

Comment: Correct your url from url: '"http://localhost/gui/calendar/add_events.php' to url: 'http://localhost/gui/calendar/add_events.php'.

Comment: Ofcourse, I'll check that :)

Comment: Oh my god, Vermicello thank you!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan — The OP isn't sending JSON. It is application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoded.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try that:

```
var data = {
    "title":"Gregor",
    "start":"2016-05-10 00:00:00",
    "end":"2016-05-10 00:00:00",
    "url":"www.renting.si"
};
var url = "http://localhost/gui/calendar/add_events.php";

$.post(url, data, function (json) {
    alert("Success here");
});
```

Care, in you code you have a double quotation mark in this line before 'http':

```
 url: '"http://localhost/gui/calendar/add_events.php',
```

Comment: Yes that quotation was the case unfortunately, thank you!